# boolean check is not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am developing the node js API and I a querying data by the URL

```
get_posts_default?pageId=ge4JqBn9F0srzHnVFHmh&asking_post=false&asking_responce=false&maxSort=-1&minSort=-1&limit=20
```

This is the function who is responsible for handling this request

```
 public async get_poset_list(userDeta: hs_I_fb_en_user_auth_paylode,pageId:string,asking_post:boolean,asking_responce:boolean,maxSort:number,minSort:number,limit:number):Promise<hs_I_fb_en_post_return[]>{
        try {
            hs_d_w("Is asking post: - "+asking_post);
            hs_d_w("Limit: - "+limit);
            if(asking_post===true){  
                hs_d_w("Asking post true");
                if(minSort<=-1 && maxSort<=-1){
                    hs_d_w("Asking post Defolt");
                    return this._postQueryes.get_only_poses(pageId,limit);
                }else{
                    if(minSort>-1){
                        hs_d_w("Asking post MIn");
                        return this._postQueryes.get_only_poses_min(pageId,minSort,limit);
                    }
                    if(maxSort>-1){
                        hs_d_w("Asking post Max");
                        return this._postQueryes.get_only_poses_max(pageId,maxSort,limit);
                    } 
                    hs_d_w("Asking post None");
                    return [];
                }
            }else{
                if(minSort<=-1 && maxSort<=-1){
                    hs_d_w("Asking talk Defolt");
                    return this._postQueryes.get_only_talkes(pageId,limit);
                }else{
                    if(minSort>-1){
                        hs_d_w("Asking talk min");
                        return this._postQueryes.get_only_talkes_min(pageId,minSort,limit);
                    }
                    if(maxSort>-1){
                        hs_d_w("Asking talk max");
                        return this._postQueryes.get_only_talkes_max(pageId,maxSort,limit);
                    }
                    hs_d_w("Asking talk none");
                    return [];
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            hs_d_w("get_poset_list : " + e);
            return Promise.reject(e)
        }
    }
```

Now if I call set **asking_post=false** or **asking_post=true** it allways call the main else area of this function

```
return this._postQueryes.get_only_talkes(pageId,limit);
```

This one.

I don't understand why it's happening? Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: `if((!!asking_post) === true)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get something from the `req.query` it will always return a `String`. So, make sure to convert it to boolean using

```
const variable = (variable == 'true')
// or
const variable = (variable === 'true')
```

On a side note, when a variable is boolean you don't have to check explicitly with `===`. This will also work

```
if(foo) {

} else {

}
```

EDIT: as  @Kamalakannan said `Boolean('string')` will not work. My apologies.

Comment: `Boolean("string")` will always return `true`, be it "true" or "false", so it won't work

Answer (score 1):

Query params are considered as `strings`. So if you check with `===`, it will be falsy.

Do string comparison, like `if ("true" === asking_post)` or `if ("false" === asking_post)`

Boolean(asking_post) will always return `true` for string values

```js
const t = Boolean("true");
const f = Boolean("false");

console.log("Value of 'true':", t);
console.log("Value of 'false':", f);
```

So don't use `Boolean(asking_post)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply convert it with JSON.parse.

```
const x = JSON.parse('true');
const y = JSON.parse('false');
```

It will return boolean values for both.

Answer (score 0):

When you get any values from `request` you always get `String` type.
So you need to convert it into Boolean first. Or just check with String.

You can do this: (I personally preferred)

```
var isTrue = (asking_post == 'true');
```

But please **be caution** to use following method:

```
var isTrue = Boolean("false");  // return true

var isTrue = !!"false";  // return true
```

Any string which is not empty will give you `true` by using the above methods.

Comment: `asking_post == 'true'` - we can use `===` here

Comment: Yes, and we can also use `==` too.

Comment: If `asking_post` is expected to be string why would we use `==`? It's confusing to everyone and implies redundant type casting.